# ¿Cómo separar una API en distintos archivos (routes)? Node.js + MySQL

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Hola a todos soy nuevo por acá. Quería saber como separar una API en varios archivos. Principalmente como poner todas las rutas en un archivo separado, intenté varias cosas viendo tutoriales pero no consigo mi resultado. Este es mi código (archivo único), quiero las rutas en otro archivo.

¡De ser posible las conecciones y eso también!

````
const mysql = require('mysql')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3050
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'shop'
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to my API!')
})

//RUTAS!!!

app.get('/customers', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers'
    connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (results.length > 0) {
            res.json(results)
        } else {
            res.send('No results!')
        }
    })
})

app.get('/customers/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ${id}`
    connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (result.length > 0) {
            res.json(result)
        } else {
            res.send('No result!')
        }
    })
})

connection.connect(error => {
    if (error) throw error
    console.log('Database server running!')
})
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`)) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

De la manera que están tus rutas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```javascript
//customer.route.js
const app = require('express')()

app.get('/customers', (req, res) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers'
    connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (results.length > 0) {
            res.json(results)
        } else {
            res.send('No results!')
        }
    })
})

app.get('/customers/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = ${id}`
    connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (result.length > 0) {
            res.json(result)
        } else {
            res.send('No result!')
        }
    })
})

module.exports = app
```

Luego haces esto en tu fichero principal.

```javascript
...mas importaciones...


const costumersRoutes = require("./routes/costumer.route")
app.use(costumersRoutes)



app.listen(...)
```

También puedes omitir la primera parte de tus rutas `/customer/...` si agregas el path en el archivo principal.

```javascript
//app.js
app.use("/costumers", costumersRoutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Asi puedes organizar tu código]

Podrías separar tu código en un archivo principal del servidor, uno para las rutas y otro como controlador del comportamiento de tu aplicacion.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, para tus futuras repuestas prioriza el uso de bloques de código sobre imagenes, ya que esta última dificulta la lectura y tanto el autor como otros usuarios queremos copiar y pegar el código para probar que la repuesta es correcta.